# This message wasn't delivered to anyone because it's too large. The limit is 10 MB. This message is 11 MB

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003

We have Exchange 2003 partially migrated over to Exchange 2010. When an external user sends a file they receive an error report from our exchange, saying the limit is 10MB. I have gone through the settings [Here](http://exchangepedia.com/2007/09/exchange-server-2007-setting-message-size-limits.html) and changed them to 50MB but I still receive the message from a test email from googlemail. Is there any other settings I may have missed or need to try.

Comment: Repeat after me: ***E-Mail is NOT a File Transfer Protocol***.  10MB is plenty for reasonable email communication.  Educate your users, or risk having your Exchange data stores become hulking behemoths and having those same users cry to you when they send a 50MB attachment to a company with reasonable message size limits. (end obligatory righteous email size rant)

Comment: I completely agree with you we are still educating our users daily. This was a one off emergency that may happen again, so I wanted to know where the setting was.

Comment: @Matt Which servers (2003 or 2010) are specified in your domain's `MX` record?  And, sometime ask me about the time that a user sent an uncompressed `.iso` of a music CD from their exchange account to to their GMail.

Comment: Even GMail's size limit is 25MB (which is why we upped ours to 25MB), so 50MB is a bit much...

Answer (score 3):

For Exchange 2003, I found this article titled, "How to set size limits for messages in Exchange Server." Here is the link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322679

For Exchange 2007 and 2010, I always go to this article titled, "Setting Message Size Limits in Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2007." Here is the link:

http://exchangepedia.com/2007/09/exchange-server-2007-setting-message-size-limits.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.